# Вопрос по умножению дробного и целого числа

Tags: java

Есть целое число и дробное. Как их умножить между собой, чтобы получить точный результат. Вариант с BigDecimal и Math.round() не рассматриваем. Есть какие-то другие средства для таких расчётов(без того.чтобы передавать числа в конструктор класса BigDecimal.Без этих плясок с бубном)? Может использование сторонних библиотек или другие средства языка? 
Вот пример: 24*0.05 = 1.2000000000000002
Как мы видим правильный ответ тут однозначно 24*0.05 = 1.2. Какв этом случае получить 1.2, а не 1.2000000000000002

Comment: Посмотрите ответ в дубликате выше, почему дробные числа так себя ведут. И как результат  - скорее нужно юзать округление чем не юзать)

Comment: вопрос немного в другом. есть ли какие-то средства,чтобы обойти это явление без применения штук вроде BigDecimal(т.к. он тормозит вычисления)

Comment: эм..`24*0.05f`  ?

Comment: хорошо. я хочу посчитать 2147483647f*6f.  Idea говорит:  1.2884901888E10. это не есть хорошо(

Comment: при подсчётах среда всегда будет считать эти числа float. Если я выхожу за диапазон float как он себя будет вести?

Comment: Вы задаете совсем разные вопросы. Тот, вопрос который вы изначально задали, лечится банально. А сейчас у вас вопрос сводится к арифметике и отображению больших чисел. Надо более четко формулировать желания)

Comment: Считайте точные значения. Отображайте форматированные. Если в ходе расчётов нужно что-то выводить - делайте это в отдельном потоке. Но поток нужно держать готовым, а то будут накладные расходы на его создание. Тут уже может помочь пул потоков.

Comment: хорошо, сформулирую итоговый вопрос. вот,например, при написании чего-то сложного.связанного с арифметикой..например игрвоой движок. для него нужны точные вычисления. С++ позволяет их осуществлять, в Java же я увидел вариант с классом BigDecimal,который  тормознет скорость работы ПО, 2 вариант-приписывать к кажой цифре f.тоже не очень хорошо. и 3 вариант-потоки,что я тоже думаю потребует доп.ресурсы. можно на джаве писать аткие сложные вещи, или лучше не изобретать велосипед и  писать на С\С++?

Answer (score 0):

Точность операций с дробными числами (с плавающей точкой) гарантируется лишь до некоторой степени. Любая библиотека или калькулятор округляют до какого-то знака.
1.2000000000000002 если округлить, то получается 1.2
1.9999999999999999 получится 2

КОнечно, можно дробное число перевести на целое, умножить. потом поделить... но это не эффективно. Я о том, чтобы 1,25 *2 = 125 *2 /100. Лучше сразу же

Я рекомендую выбрать количество знаков после запятой

```
new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(double)).setScale(yourScale,     BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: класс BigDecimal это хорошо,но как я понял с ним вычисления происходят медленней. я пытаюсь понять,можно ли в java безболезненно(без всяких bigdecimal) проводить серьезные вычисления(например разработать движок для игры), или лучше это поручить С++ в котором без всяких свистелок и округлений получается нужный результат стандартными средствами